# wrap text in knitr::kable table cell using "\n"

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable

How can I wrap a cell in a `knitr::kable` table cell using `\n`?

---

I want to generate a .rmd file containing some tables where one column needs text wrapping. The places where the wrapping should occur are marked with `\n`. I tried (this is a standalone .rmd document):

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

## A Table with text wrap

```{r cars}
knitr::kable(data.frame(col1 = c("a", "b"), col2 = c("one\ntwo", "three\nfour")))
```
````

..but this doesn't work. Instead of staying in `col2`, the wrapped part lives on the next line of `col1`.

[image]

Expected output is:

```
col1 | col2
-------------
a    | one
     | two
b    | three
     | four
```

Solutions using other packages than `knitr` are welcome as long as they allow to print (nearly) as nice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**A fire-and-forget solution** for flexible dual HTML/PDF of standard tables. It incorporates kableExtra's linebreak function outlined by @snoram.
*Assumption: You use `<br>` as your line break indicator.*

````
```{r}
knit_table(df1)
```
````

[image]

#### Code

```
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

knit_table <- function(df){
  if (is_html_output()) {
    df %>%
      kable("html", escape = F) %>%
      kable_styling()
  } else {
    df <- data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) {gsub("<br>", "\n", x)}), stringsAsFactors = F)

    df %>%  
      mutate_all(linebreak) %>%
      kable("latex", booktabs = T, escape = F)  
  }
}
```

#### Data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c("a", "b"),
                  col2 = c("one<br>two", "three<br>four"))
```

Comment: Thanks @Roman for this extremely simple solution. It is exactly what I was searching for, since the \n's were a choice I can easily change to <br>. This however only works for html output, at least for me. Does it also work for pdf output for you?

Comment: You both are absolutely right. I adapted the approach for dual-use.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't mind using `kableExtra` you can definitely achieve this, here is one example:

```
library(kableExtra)
knitr::kable(data.frame(col1 = c("a", "b"), col2 = linebreak(c("one\ntwo", "three\nfour"))),
             escape = FALSE)
```

[image]

More details [here](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/best_practice_for_newline_in_latex_table.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this throws an error for me: `Error in linebreak(c("one\ntwo", "three\nfour")) : could not find function "linebreak"`. What package does the `linebreak` function come from?

Comment: `kableExtra`, you first need to install and then add library(kableExtra) to your script...

Comment: Thanks, @snoram. I unfortunately had an old version of kableExtra installed. Changed that. Now the code runs. For pdf output it works perfectly, for html output it produces an empty `col2`. Does it also work for html output for you?

Comment: I just checked and it doesn't work in `html`. So instead you could use Roman's solution or open a new question if it is important to have one solution that works for both.