# How to embed escape characters ("\n", "\t") into dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, r-markdown, escaping

**How to insert escape characters into dataframe?**

It will be useful for the formatting of text data into table packages.

We could be use one universal solution for every table package (my hope).

But now we should employ a lot of approaches for the every case (*depends on libraries and output formates: pdf, html*).

It is really uncomfortable!

**For example, we have next data**

```
df <- data.frame("names" = c("a long long long long long ... pretty long name of the our story","Here is also long, but a little shorter"))
```

**We see a normal output**

```
                                                             names
1 a long long long long long ... pretty long name of the our story
2                          Here is also long, but a little shorter
```

**But how we can achieve this output ("\n")?**

```
                                                             names
1                                       a long long long long long 
                             ... pretty long name of the our story
2                          Here is also long, but a little shorter
```

---

**I promised to add a simple example:**

*knit to HTML, in PDF doesn't work*

````
```{r warning = FALSE, echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, include=FALSE,}
library(flextable)
library(gt)

#data
df <- data.frame("names" = c("a long long long \n long long ... <br> pretty long name of the our story","Here is also long, but a little shorter"))
#table one
table3 <- flextable(df)
table3 <- set_table_properties(table3, layout = "autofit", width = .5)
table3

#table two
table4 <- gt(df) %>% fmt_markdown(columns = everything())
table4
```

<center>
<caption>Table in flextable </caption>
</center>
`r table3`

<center>
<caption>Table in gt </caption>
</center>
`r table4`
````

In the first case - works \n, in the second - /br/ and there are only two packages!

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you want something like `stringr::str_wrap()`.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Interesting. I try to realize my task with ```str_wrap``` now. And return after. But question is still opened. It will be cool to embed escaping without any bells ans whistles.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento No, can't make desired output(

Comment: you could include the line break as "\n" on the wanted position of the cell value and then use the [huxtable](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/huxtable/vignettes/huxtable.html) package to print it: huxtable::as_huxtable(df) this way the print out will be a table where the "\n" are converted to actual line breaks... not sure if that is what you are looking for

Comment: @DPH Not with ```huxtable```, but you are right. I want to prepare text data for using into table packages. "\t" is also useful.

Comment: @manro what are you trying to achive exactly ... possibly you are looking to print a table in markdown where linebreaks are shown as such? If so the kableExtra might be an option like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52944533/wrap-text-in-knitrkable-table-cell-using-n)

Comment: @DPH Yes, we are near. Not only in the rmarkdown, in the viewer too. But I want to find a more universal solution. Because in one situation we should use ```kableExtra``` in another - ```gt``` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Don't add any line breaks to your text!! This is absolutely unnecessary. All you need is the skillful use of the `kableExtra` package. Note the code below is the content from the RMarkdown.
The document created with it can be found [here](https://rpubs.com/MarekFiolka/841535).

Add everything from `## RMarkdown Start` to `## RMarkdown End` to RMarkdown
Of course, don't forget to remove the comment characters before the code blocks (**#```**)!!

````
## RMarkdown Start
---
title: "LongText"
author: "Marek Fiołka"
date: "30 11 2021"
output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: default
---

#```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
#```

Prepare data frame with long text

#```{r echo=TRUE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

n=50
df = tibble(
  id = 1:n,
  txt = stri_rand_lipsum(n)
)
#```

See the data frame in a typical display

#```{r}
print(df)
#```

View data frame formatted with Kable Extra for HTML

#```{r}
df %>% kbl() %>%
  kable_styling()
#```

View data frame formatted with Kable Extra for PDF

#```{r}
df %>% kbl() %>%
  kable_paper(full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = T, border_right = T) %>%
  column_spec(2, width = "30em")

## RMarkdown End
````

This way you can create not only html documents but also corresponding pdf documents. Below is a fragment of a document created in this format. Note that in this case you have to use `kable_paper` with `column_spec` instead of `kable_styling`.

[image]

Hope this is what you were looking for.

### Update

````
## RMarkdown Start
---
title: "LongText"
author: "Marek Fiołka"
date: "30 11 2021"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---

#```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
#```

Prepare data frame with long text

#```{r echo=TRUE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

n=10
df = tibble(
  id = 1:n,
  txt = stri_rand_lipsum(n)
)
#```

See the data frame in a typical display

#```{r echo=TRUE}
print(df)
#```

View data frame formatted with [kableExtra](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/) for HTML

#```{r}
df %>% kbl() %>%
  kable_styling()
#```

View data frame formatted with [kableExtra](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/) for PDF

#```{r}
df %>% kbl() %>%
  kable_paper(full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = T, border_right = T) %>%
  column_spec(2, width = "30em")

#```

View data frame formatted with [gt](https://gt.rstudio.com/index.html) (only for HTML)

#```{r}
library(gt)
df %>% gt %>% 
  fmt_markdown(columns = everything()) %>%
    tab_options(table.width = px(400))
#```

View data frame formatted with [flextable](https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/overview.html) HTML & PDF

#```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(flextable)

df %>% flextable %>% width(2, width = 6, unit = "in")
#```

View data frame formatted with [huxtable](https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/) HTML & PDF

#```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(huxtable)

df %>% as_hux %>% 
  set_width(1) %>% 
  set_right_border(everywhere, 1, brdr(3, "double", "grey"))
#```
## RMarkdown End
````

Comment: Thanks, Mr. Marek. Can you try to make this trick for some other table packages? (knit to PDF)```gt or flextable?``` As I said in my question, sometimes we need to use different instruments which can give their features for our task. Bounty is prepared for you ;)

Comment: Here you are. Now you have it in four different ways. I also updated the [report](https://rpubs.com/MarekFiolka/841535) on my RPubs.

Comment: Cool, your solution looks like universal one?

Comment: I don't know if my solution can be called universal. It seems to solve your problem in most of the ways possible. I would suggest to get acquainted one library (I recommend kable Extra or [kableExtra](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/) or [flextable](https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/) ) and fine-tune the table view that suits you best.

Comment: I haven't any task now, only preparing for the future deeds. Dzięki, panu Marek ;) I'll add a bounty to you in the last day for better impact of the post ;)